# Installing conda recipes from a Binstar channel

Tags: python-2.7, conda, binstar

I'm having some trouble installing packages that I've uploaded to my Binstar channel: https://binstar.org/Judowill/PyVCF

I used the `conda skeleton` command to generate a build-recipe from PyPi. After some tinkering everything built and uploaded as expected.

When I use the suggested command:

`conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/judowill pyvcf`

I get a `Error: No packages found matching: pyvcf` error.

Am I missing something? Is there a long lag time between upload and availability?

Using the `--debug` flag I get the following output:

```
conda --debug install -c https://conda.binstar.org/judowill pyvcf
DEBUG:conda.fetch:channel_urls=('https://conda.binstar.org/judowill/linux-64/', 'http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/', 'http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64/')
Fetching package metadata: INFO:stdoutlog:Fetching package metadata: 
.DEBUG:dotupdate:fetching repodata: http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64/ ...
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): repo.continuum.io
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /pkgs/pro/linux-64/repodata.json.bz2 HTTP/1.1" 200 16299
.DEBUG:dotupdate:fetching repodata: http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/ ...
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /pkgs/free/linux-64/repodata.json.bz2 HTTP/1.1" 200 86460
.DEBUG:dotupdate:fetching repodata: https://conda.binstar.org/judowill/linux-64/ ...
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): conda.binstar.org
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /judowill/linux-64/repodata.json.bz2 HTTP/1.1" 200 408

INFO:stdoutlog:

DEBUG:conda.plan:H0 specs=['pyvcf', 'conda']
Error: No packages found matching: pyvcf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After plenty of putzing it seems like binstar has a weird bug. If you create a package with a CamelCase  name (such as PyVCF) you'll have issues. The conda-install will check the channel for `pyvcf` (even if you specify `PyVCF`) and it won't find it.

I'm submitting a bug report. But to solve the issue quickly, just remove the package from binstar and re-upload with all lower-case.

Comment: How did you create the package on binstar? conda-build should prevent you from creating a package name with uppercase letters.

Comment: When you create packages through the website first it does not enforce this. Also, if you create the package on the Web with CamelCase and then use binstar-upload it puts it into the non-normalized package name.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug.  `conda` always uses lowercase names for packages.  From the documentation at
http://conda.pydata.org/docs/intro.html :

"Conda package names are normalized, and may contain only lowercase alpha characters, numeric digits, underscores, or hyphens. "

Comment: When creating a package from the web interface (like I did) this convention is not enforced. When I downloaded the channel definition file it had PyVCF in camel case.